# Having trouble with Bcrypt C# Salt

Tags: c#, bcrypt

Hello everyone I am currently trying to match my PHP login system which uses

```
define('PASSWORD_ENCRYPTION', "bcrypt"); 
define('PASSWORD_SHA512_ITERATIONS', 25000); 
define('PASSWORD_BCRYPT_COST', "13"); 

define('PASSWORD_SALT', "/8Wncr26eAmxD1l6cAF9F8"); //22 characters to be appended on first 7 characters that will be generated using PASSWORD_ info above
```

My C#:

```
            string myPassword = this.password_txt.Text;
            string mySalt = "$2a$13$/8Wncr26eAmxD1l6cAF9F8";
            string hashed = BCrypt.HashPassword(myPassword, mySalt);
```

Problem: My hashed password I make with C# does not match the login PHP hashed password on database...

Comment: You shouldn't ever need to do this. All you need to make sure is that hashes generated by BCrypt.Net can be verified with the PHP lib and vice versa.

Comment: Aron can you show me an example of how this is correctly achieved?

Comment: Your PHP script must of used a different `PASSWORD_SALT` when it hashed into the database, how do the database hashes look like? (Show example) because I ran your script it gives perfect identical results to BCrypt. If the 22 characters after the `$2a$13$` are different in database to the `PASSWORD_SALT`, then you had a different SALT, you must use that different salt now instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your full function looks like this

```
/**
 * Hash given password.
 * @param string $password Unhashed password.
 * @return string Hashed password.
 */
 public function hashPassword($password) {
    //this salt will be used in both algorithms
    //for bcrypt it is required to look like this,
    //for sha512 it is not required but it can be used 
    $salt = "$2a$" . PASSWORD_BCRYPT_COST . "$" . PASSWORD_SALT;

    if(PASSWORD_ENCRYPTION == "bcrypt") {
        $newPassword = crypt($password, $salt);
    }
    else {
        $newPassword = $password;
        for($i=0; $i<PASSWORD_SHA512_ITERATIONS; $i++)
            $newPassword = hash('sha512',$salt.$newPassword.$salt);
    }

    return $newPassword;
 }
```

**EDIT:** More research suggested that `$2a$` which seems to be `BlowFish Encryption` from research. (http://php.net/crypt)

> **CRYPT_BLOWFISH** - Blowfish hashing with a salt as follows: "$2a$",
>   "$2x$" or "$2y$", a two digit cost parameter, "$", and 22 characters
>   from the alphabet "./0-9A-Za-z". Using characters outside of this
>   range in the salt will cause crypt() to return a zero-length string.
>   The two digit cost parameter is the base-2 logarithm of the iteration
>   count for the underlying Blowfish-based hashing algorithmeter and must
>   be in range 04-31, values outside this range will cause crypt() to
>   fail. Versions of PHP before 5.3.7 only support "$2a$" as the salt
>   prefix: PHP 5.3.7 introduced the new prefixes to fix a security
>   weakness in the Blowfish implementation. Please refer to » this
>   document for full details of the security fix, but to summarise,
>   developers targeting only PHP 5.3.7 and later should use "$2y$" in
>   preference to "$2a$".
>
> It must begin with "$2", optional "a", "$", two digits, "$", and 22
>   base 64 digits. The rest of the string is ignored. The presence of the
>   optional "a" means that a NUL is to be appended to the password before
>   it is used as a key. The two digits set the cost parameter. The 22
>   base 64 digits encode the salt.

`$13$` is called the `cost`. (how much times to loop the encryption).
Now the salt itself is encoded in `base64` which you have to decode it before using it with `Eksblowfish`

> Eksblowfish, states for (expensive key schedule blowfish, is a cost
>   parameterizable and salted variation of the blowfish block cipher.)

Anyways to summarize it you have to use this
http://bcrypt.codeplex.com/

which should be like this

```
int PASSWORD_BCRYPT_COST = 13;
string PASSWORD_SALT = "/8Wncr26eAmxD1l6cAF9F8";
string salt = "$2a$" + PASSWORD_BCRYPT_COST + "$" + PASSWORD_SALT;
string password  "test123abc";
var hash = BCrypt.HashPassword(password, salt);
textBox1.Text = hash;
```

Password = test123abc
Output for `textbox1` was: `$2a$13$/8Wncr26eAmxD1l6cAF9FuVnazDlahXc73He5NB1GKNYG7v3mOOyS`

[image: C# test program screenshot]

Also ran your code in php http://ideone.com/8piXMq

php Output for

```
echo hashPassword("test123abc");
```

Output for php was: `$2a$13$/8Wncr26eAmxD1l6cAF9FuVnazDlahXc73He5NB1GKNYG7v3mOOyS`

C#
`$2a$13$/8Wncr26eAmxD1l6cAF9FuVnazDlahXc73He5NB1GKNYG7v3mOOyS`
PHP
`$2a$13$/8Wncr26eAmxD1l6cAF9FuVnazDlahXc73He5NB1GKNYG7v3mOOyS`

As you can see the answers are both **IDENTICAL**

As you can see from the BCrypt HashPassword implementation it decodes the base64 salt and re-encrypts your new password with the salt you specified.

```
/// <summary>
/// Hash a password using the OpenBSD bcrypt scheme.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="password">The password to hash.</param>
/// <param name="salt">The salt to hash with (perhaps generated
/// using <c>BCrypt.GenerateSalt</c>).</param>
/// <returns>The hashed password.</returns>
public static string HashPassword(string password, string salt) {
    if (password == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("password");
    }
    if (salt == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("salt");
    }

    char minor = (char)0;

    if (salt[0] != '$' || salt[1] != '2') {
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid salt version");
    }

    int offset;
    if (salt[1] != '$') {
        minor = salt[2];
        if (minor != 'a' || salt[3] != '$') {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid salt revision");
        }
        offset = 4;
    } else {
        offset = 3;
    }

    // Extract number of rounds
    if (salt[offset + 2] > '$') {
        throw new ArgumentException("Missing salt rounds");
    }

    int rounds = Int32.Parse(salt.Substring(offset, 2), NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);

    byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password + (minor >= 'a' ? "\0" : String.Empty));
    byte[] saltBytes = DecodeBase64(salt.Substring(offset + 3, 22),
                                    BCRYPT_SALT_LEN);

    BCrypt bcrypt = new BCrypt();

    byte[] hashed = bcrypt.CryptRaw(passwordBytes, saltBytes, rounds);

    StringBuilder rs = new StringBuilder();

    rs.Append("$2");
    if (minor >= 'a') {
        rs.Append(minor);
    }
    rs.Append('$');
    if (rounds < 10) {
        rs.Append('0');
    }
    rs.Append(rounds);
    rs.Append('$');
    rs.Append(EncodeBase64(saltBytes, saltBytes.Length));
    rs.Append(EncodeBase64(hashed,
                           (bf_crypt_ciphertext.Length * 4) - 1));

    return rs.ToString();
}
```

Comment: no problem, it seems there is no difference to what code you used then what I used.. I still don't know why yours didn't work.